# Does it matter where my furnace condensate pump gets power from?

Tags: electrical, furnace

The existing condensate pump for my furnace recently died.  It was hard-wired directly into the electrical panel of the furnace but I was able to disconnect it.  However, when looking for a new pump, all the models I found had a standard 115V wall plug.

I have plugged it in to a nearby outlet and the pump is working fine, but is this the best method?  Would it be better for me to cut off the wall plug and wire it directly into the furnace like the previous one was?

Answer (score 4):

Are there any other connectors (not power)? If these are all connected up then I wouldn't have thought it matters.

The only possible thing I can think of is that if the condensate pump power is turned off and the furnace keeps running it could cause problems - but I assume that there are alarms/indicators for this (how did you know the original failed?).

It might look neater if you do use the furnace's electrical panel - assuming it delivers enough power of course.

Comment: The new pump has two low-voltage leads that apparently would be used to shut down the furnace in case the pump fills with water, however the original pump did not have these so I have not connected them on the new one.  The original was also a 115VAC pump, so I might just wire it into the furnace, as you mentioned, it would look neater.  Maybe I'm just lucky to have a power outlet so close to my furnace!

Comment: @Wally - I was more concerned with connectors that the new pump didn't have, so I wouldn't be worried about not wiring these new ones in.

Answer (score 0):

Check the specifications for the original pump, or measure the voltage at its power terminals on the furnace's control board.  The furnace may not supply 115VAC to the pump: other components on the board will be driven by lower voltages, so it's possible that that the pump could be too.  (Though it's unlikely, it could even have a DC motor).

Other than that, I agree with [ChrisF's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/does-it-matter-where-my-furnace-condensate-pump-gets-power-from/2763#2763).

Comment: I did check, the original pump was 115VAC as well.